# Consuming NETTCP WCF service from UWP app.

Tags: wcf, migration, win-universal-app, nettcpbinding

This works perfectly for a win8 store app but have not had any luck consuming the same service from a UWP app.

Is this supported? What is it's current status?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a WCF NETTCP service in a Win 10 application.
You solution is to add a new endpoint in your web server configuration

Here is a sample :

```
<endpoint name="webHttpBinding" 
behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" 
address="/productProviderRest.svc" 
binding="webHttpBinding" 
contract="WCFServices.IProductProvider" />
```

Do not forget to add a behavior, since it's mandatory :

```
<behaviors> 
  <endpointBehaviors> 
    <behavior name="webHttpBehavior"> 
      <webHttp helpEnabled ="true" /> 
    </behavior> 
  </endpointBehaviors> 
</behaviors>
```

Then you have to expose your methods to be able to call them from your uwp application.
Something like that :

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate="/count")]
public int GetCount(){
...
}

[WebGet(UriTemplate="/list
public List<Products>  GetProducts(){
...
}
```

You have another solution : Recreate a full server solution with Web API support :)

Comment: I was able to use .nettcp in windows 8.1 apps why not with windows 10? Is this something that Microsoft intends to implement?